# Dependencies info to download in debian based OS after an installed package

Tags: debian, dependencies

How to know dependencies to download in debian based OS after the package was installed perfectly ?

This is given as clear information when installing one, but if it's been installed that information can't be obtained again, so how to obtain such at any time else as users intend to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependencies to download depend on both the package to be ultimately installed, and the set of packages which are already present. This is what `apt` and similar tools determine and show you when you install a package.

Once a package is installed, you’ll need some manual work. `apt-rdepends` will list all the dependencies of a package, recursively; this will allow you to determine the maximum set of packages you’d need to download. For example,

```
$ apt-rdepends msitools
msitools
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  Depends: libgcab-1.0-0 (>= 0.4)
  Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.18.0)
  Depends: libgsf-1-114 (>= 1.14.8)
  Depends: libmsi0 (>= 0.93)
  Depends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16)
  Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.6.27)
libc6
  Depends: libgcc1
libgcc1
  Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-6)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
gcc-8-base
[...]
```

with suitable post-processing — in this instance,  `| grep Depends | sort -u` — would allow you to determine that installing `msitools` in Debian 10 today requires `gcc-8-base` (8.3.0-6), `libblkid1` (2.17.2 or later), `libbz2-1.0`, `libc6` (2.28 or later), `libffi6` (3.0.4 or later), `libgcab-1.0-0` (0.4 or later), `libgcc1` (1:4.2 or later), `libglib2.0-0` (2.39.4 or later), `libgsf-1-114` (1.14.8 or later), `libgsf-1-common` (1.14.45-1 or later), `libicu63` (63.1-1~ or later), `liblzma5` (5.1.1alpha+20120614 or later), `libmount1` (2.28 or later), `libmsi0` (0.93 or later), `libpcre3`, `libselinux1` (2.6-3~ or later), `libstdc++6` (5.2 or later), `libuuid1` (2.16 or later), `libxml2` (2.7.4 or later), and `zlib1g` (1:1.2.3.3 or later).

Feeding all that to `apt-get download`, without the version constraints, would give you all the package files necessary. (The version constraints aren’t needed because all the above are satisfiable using the latest versions in Debian 10.)

This is a straightforward dependency tree, but the analysis becomes more complex as soon as virtual packages or alternative dependencies are available.

Answer (score 0):

This became a bit long for a comment.

What is it that you've installed? And how?

In most cases packages depend on other packages such that software is usable after being installed. If you've been installing something where the software has dependencies that are not dependencies of the package, I would expect the source of the package you installed to provide some information. If the package didn't have proper dependencies, there are a couple of options for how it could have output them. You can try to see if there's any usable documentation in the package with `dpkg -l <package name>`.

Comment: I interpreted the question as referring to installing a package from Debian, and wanting to find the information shown by `apt` (the list of other packages to install to satisfy the dependencies) after the package is installed.

Comment: That makes more sense.